# How to Search Images from SDCard?

Tags: android, image, sd-card

I have done an Application which shows the images which are stored in drawable folder.

Now I want to implement an application which Searches images from SDcard/Phone Memory and display them in Thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

try this with some Modification it may help u..

```
   private void walkdir(File dir) 
    {
    String filePattent = ".jpge";
    String filePattentCAP = ".JPGE";
            File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
            if (listFile != null) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) 
                    {
                        walkdir(listFile[i]);
                    }
                     else if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(filePattent) || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(filePattentCAP)) 
                    {
                                fileName.add(listFile[i].getName());
                                filePath.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```